# How to send sms, detecting text in textview?

Tags: iphone, sms, textview

I want that when user clicks on certain text,(like call, sms, mail), then corresponding activity should happen ie, when user clicks on call then an action sheet should appear with actions whether you want to save or call etc, similarly for sms and mail.I used textview and gave detection for numbers and email. So for call and mail it is working fine. But how to detect for sms?Because when I give number detection it will automatically show call action sheet ie save or call or cancel.But I want following action sheet, which sms, open, copy, cancel:

[image: Following image]

I tried using sms//"91123456", but it is not working. I know I can directly launch message picker but do not want this, I want to show default action sheet.I tried this in html and it is working but I want to do in native.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;`?

For more data detector types see this [UIKit Data Types Reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Yes I did, but for numbers by default it will show calls options not for ams.

Comment: You know any other way of handling this?